# Extract.String Null? No Luck.

Tags: java, android, eclipse, null

I get a nullPointerException on status variable on this line of code : `if (view.getId() == R.id.button && status.equals("Dorado")`. Now ive looked on many threads in here and i havnt really gotten much luck with this exception. Like many others, i pass a string from activity 1 to activity 2, except this string is extracted from the textview when it is pressed(Dorado). 
Activity 1:

```
TextView text = (TextView) view;
        String selection = text.getText().toString();
        Bundle b = new Bundle();
        b.putString("Selection", selection);
        Intent i = new Intent(MunicipioList.this,SubestacionInfo.class);
      i.putExtra("extra", b);
        startActivity(i);
```

Acitivity 2:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_subestacion_info);

    Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
    if (extras != null) {
        extras = extras.getBundle("extra");
        status = extras.getString("Selection");

    }
}
```

I know the bundle isnt necessary i was just experimenting since i was still getting Null with other codes. Ah one more thing, the status varoable is global, declared right at the beginning of the activity as "public String status;" so i dont believe that to be the issue here, Any help? :)

Answer (score 1):

Lets break this down.  If you get an NPE in this line:

```
   if (view.getId() == R.id.button && status.equals("Dorado"))
```

then either:

- `view` is `null`, or
- `R.id` is `null` (which I think is impossible), or
- `status` is `null`.

You should be able to work out which with a debugger, or by adding a traceprint.  But I suspect that it is `status`.

You say:

> Ah one more thing, the status variable is global, declared right at the beginning of the activity as "public String status;" so I don't believe that to be the issue here.

That declaration does not initialise `status`.  Did you initialize `status` *following the declaration?*  If not, its initial value will be `null`, and that would be sufficient to cause an NPE ... if you never changed it!

Comment: Sorry for the lat reply, and thank you! i figured out the problem. The main problem, apart not initializing the variable, but i had one more intention on another activity that was messing with the data being send to "activity 2". Thanks again!